# Como carregar dados para o Chunk?

Tags: r, rmarkdown

Estou me aventurando no  Rmarkdown, achei uma ferramenta bem interessante. Acontece que estou com problemas, eu acho que é básica de iniciante, quando compliava o Rmarkdown com knitr ele dá o erro de objeto desconhecido:

```
   Quitting from lines 13-16 (doc.Rmd) 
   Error in inherits(x, "list") : objeto 'tab.genova' não encontrado
   Calls: <Anonymous> ... withCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> eval -> eval -> kable -> inherits
  Execução interrompida
```

Pesquisei sobre, vi que tinha que importar os meus dados usando a função `read.csv()` ou `source` que geralmente é um problema que iniciantes geralmente esbarram.

Tentei esses comandos e não estou conseguindo, acredito que seja um erro que estou cometendo e não percebendo.

A integridade dos códigos presentes nos chunks, eles estão operando normalmente, pois quando dou `run current chunk` o gráfico e a tabela são plotados normalmente e sem erros.

````
```{r TabGenova, echo=FALSE}
library(knitr)
kable(tab.genova)

```
````

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Utilizar o `rmarkdown` pra criar um relatório implica em mesclar a parte textual da análise com os códigos em `R`. Por isso, é necessário carregar explicitamente cada pacote ou arquivo necessário para realizar a análise. Portanto, faça o seguinte:

1. Copie o arquivo `.csv` com os teus dados para o mesmo diretório do arquivo `.Rmd`
2. Dentro do RStudio, vá ao menu `Session > Set Working Directory > To Source File Location`
3. Adicione o seguinte chunk ao teu código, em algum local antes da primeira análise a ser realizada:

(texto colocado por causa de um bug no SO)

````
```{r LeituraDeDados, echo=FALSE}
tab.genova <- read.csv(file="ArquivoComOsDados.csv")
head(tab.genova) # para conferir as seis primeiras linhas e ver se deu certo
```
````

4. Se o comando do item acima der problema, talvez seja necessário adicionar o argumento `sep=";"` ou `sep="\t"` ao `read.csv` para informar qual é o separador de coluna correto. Descubra isto abrindo `ArquivoComOsDados.csv` em algum editor de textos.

Comment: @Macrus Nunes mais uma vez salvando a pátria kkk Muito obrigado amigo, funcionou certinho o que você me instruiu. Essa parte da `Session` eu não sabia, estava fazendo tudo errado, pelos tutoriais percebi que essa parte passa bem batido ou nem falaram e no meu caso ali tive que acrescentar o `sep=";"` no `read.csv`.